# Monitoring wallet transactions

Tags: c#-4.0, ethereum, cryptocurrency, cryptoapi

I am using the Zapper app to track a crypto wallet address, and it seems that the Zapper app provides comprehensive information about transactions for this address across various chains such as BTC, ETH, Optimism, Arbitrum, etc.

https://zapper.xyz/account/0x4d3711c1effbc584127f03b3c3054f18f0cb3870?tab=history

My question is, are there any free libraries/APIs that I can rely on to develop software that lists transactions for a given wallet address across all chains? I prefer not to depend on third-party websites/apps like Zapper. The programming language I frequently use is C#. I appreciate your assistance, thank you.

Comment: like Etherscan? It offers APIs that allow you to retrieve information from the Ethereum blockchain, including transactions. They provide both free and premium API services.

Comment: i guess so, but there lot of chains... you mean i need to interact with different api to get transaction information of all chains ?

Comment: yes. Currently, I don't have a better method to retrieve transaction information across all chains simultaneously.